# How to send back the values inside a void function to main function in C?

Tags: c

How can I send back the value inside a void function to the main function if the condition restricts me from using the non-void function to return those values?

here's my example code:

```
void calcTotalPaid(float total){
    float totalPaid=0;
    totalPaid += total;
}
```

Comment: What other conditions are there? That is to say, is it really the case you can change any aspect of the function whatsoever, other than its return type, and edit the `main` function to call the edited function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a pointer to a variable that will receive the result and use that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calcTotalPaid(float* res, float total){
    float totalPaid=0;
    totalPaid = totalPaid + total;
    *res = totalPaid;
}

int main(void) {
    float value = 0;
    calcTotalPaid(&value, 3.14);
    printf("%f\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Here is the explanation:

If you use a void function then it never returns a value into a called function which is here `int main()`. It shows an error.

You are passing the argument value into the parameter (a local variable that is declared when declaring the function prototype), so what if you pass the address of that argument into the calling function? Yes, using a pointer variable, you should pass the argument memory location.

In the called function, you have the memory address of that particular argument. Whenever the new values are inserted into that argument (which is now a local variable), it saves on that memory location because we have here that address of memory location.

### Here is your program:

```c
#include<stdio.h>//preprocessor directive for function printf()
void calTotalPaid (float *pointer, float total)//function declartion and
//definition of function
{
    float totalpaid = 0;
    totalpaid = totalpaid + total;
    *pointer = totalpaid;
}

int main ()
{
    float value, total = 0;
    calTotalPaid (&value, total);//calling the function and passing the memory 
    //location to the function parameter so if function changed the value stored 
    //at value's memory location it will change in entire program.
    printf ("The value is %f\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are thinking correctly, but it is probably easier to say, when you pass the original address as a pointer, you can update the value at that address within the function and the changes will be available back in the caller. Update your formatting and paragraph (so that sentences begin with Captials, etc..) and it will be worth my vote.

Comment: Thank you Guys for editing, I don't have much exp on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Sumit Baloda Welcome to the community. This is off-topic but I feel you are using the word "so" as a [filler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)#In_English). You may also refer to https://www.grammarly.com/blog/how-we-use-filler-words/.

Comment: Yes, in my personal notes I use a lot of "so" words. So sorry (LOL for "so") thanks for the link

Comment: @PalLaden - we will call that good enough and pass along the promised vote in a show of good-faith `:)`

Answer (score 0):

use call by reference technique. Pass address of a variable from main to  calcTotalPaid(), and store the address in a pointer variable.

```
void  calcTotalPaid(float * total_paid , float total){
 *total_paid = 0 + total;
}
```